# Reading from JSON and extracting a row

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe

[image]

I want to extract the id and then append the same in the link below

[https://www.whatdropsnow.com/api/v1/products/?brands={id}](https://www.whatdropsnow.com/api/v1/products/?brands=%7Bid%7D)

It will iterate over each `id` and extract `id`, `name`, `slug`, and `release_at` from the response(received after hitting the url) and store it in tabular format

I have developed a rudimentary code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
#from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests
import sqlite3 as db
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import requests
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

url = "https://www.whatdropsnow.com/api/v1/brands"
r = requests.get(url)
f=r.json()
new = pd.DataFrame(f["data"])

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("Read Data from JSON").config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0').getOrCreate()

def only_dict(d):
    return ast.literal_eval(str(d))
A = json_normalize(new['attributes'].apply(only_dict).tolist()).add_prefix('')
B=  json_normalize(new['links'].apply(only_dict).tolist()).add_prefix('')
new = new.join(A).join(B).drop(columns='attributes').drop(columns='links')
C = new[['id', 'slug', 'name']]
new_data=spark.createDataFrame(new)
#brand_id
for index, row in C.iterrows():
    a=row['id']
    url='https://www.whatdropsnow.com/api/v1/products/?brands='
    updated_url=url+a
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.get(updated_url, headers=headers, auth='')
    #response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth='')
    #response = requests.get(url)
    g=response.json()
    #points = json.loads(requests.get(updated_url))
    #recs = g['data']['type']
    [i['type']for i in g['data']]
```

Its not getting executed.Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "Its not getting executed". Are you getting an error? Are you not receiving the result you are expecting? If so, what is the result? And what are you expecting?

Comment: I am not receiving the result.Its running for long.I haveto cancel the execution

Comment: Add a print statement to the for loop to see it's actually progressing. Depending on how many rows C has and how long the requests take it can take a while.